# How can you hide Java compiler path VSCode?

Tags: java, terminal, visual-studio-code

When I run a java program in vscode's integrated terminal, the full java path displays as a large box of text. Is there any way to get ride of this?

> /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-13.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java --enable-preview -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -cp "/Users/myusername/Library/Application Support/Code/User/workspaceStorage/alotofnumbers/redhat.java/jdt_ws/foldername/bin"

Comment: That's the command it's running--it's just a terminal. Why does it matter?

Comment: It clutters my screen quite a lot when I'm running bigger programs. Just a personal preference

Answer (score 4):

Go to File->Preferences->Settings and search this text **Java › Debug › Settings: Console** then select **internalConsole**.

Look at **DEBUG CONSOLE** for output.

Answer (score 0):

you could let it output in debug console instead of terminal channel as a workaround,

add `"console": "internalConsole"` in your **launch.json**

```
"configurations": [
       {
         "type": "java",
         "name": "CodeLens (Launch) - App",
         "request": "launch",
         "mainClass": "com.test.maven.App",
         "console": "internalConsole",
         "projectName": "my.app"
       }
     ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Install Code Runner Extension in vs code **-->**

Click on the settings icon on the Code runner extension  **-->**

select Extension settings  **-->**
Scroll and check for **Code-runner: Show Execution Message** uncheck it and then reload the Vs Code

Now run any language code java or python, long Path won't be available,

Only **Output is displayed**