# Long codes before output in VSCODE (Java)

Tags: java, macos, visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Studio Code to run a simple Java "Hello World" program. But I also get some long codes before my output "Hello, World!".

*myusername hi %  cd /Users/myusername/Desktop/Programming/hi ; /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-15.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=n,suspend=y,address=localhost:51164 --enable-preview -XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -cp "/Users/myusername/Library/Application Support/Code/User/workspaceStorage/9d9a27fdd962858fd296255e0827be55/redhat.java/jdt_ws/hi_a18a0468/bin" App
Hello, World!*

I don't really understand these codes before or the reason for it, is that normal? How could I remove these codes from my terminal and make my output simple?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you hide Java compiler path VSCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59696109/how-can-you-hide-java-compiler-path-vscode)

Answer (score 0):

These are execution scripts and VS Code displays them to let developers know what's going on during this process, including

1. the current used JDK: `Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-15.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java`
2. network and displaying message rules: `agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=n,suspend=y,address=localhost:51164 --enable-preview -XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -cp`
3. classpath and cache location: `/Users/myusername/Library/Application Support/Code/User/workspaceStorage/9d9a27fdd962858fd296255e0827be55/redhat.java/jdt_ws/hi_a18a0468/bin`
4. the name of current .java file: `App`

There're some ways to get clear output without these scripts:

1. Set `"console": "internalConsole"` in [launch.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-debugging#_configure), the result will be displayed in **Debug Console**:

[image]

2. Set `"console": "externalTerminal"` in [launch.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-debugging#_configure), the result will be displayed in the **new opened terminal**:

[image]

3. Install **[Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner)** and add the following code in Settings.json, the result will be shown purely in **OUTPUT**:

   ```
    "code-runner.clearPreviousOutput": true,
    "code-runner.showExecutionMessage": false,
   ```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

MacOS set default Java (JDK) Open Terminal

Step 1. `/usr/libexec/java_home -V`

Step 2. export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8`

Step 3. java -version

```
java version "1.8.0_211"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_211-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.211-b12, mixed mode)
Up:~ xxx$
```

Good jobs.